> Task :react-native-fast-opencv:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
I have installed the library version 0.30.1. It's working fine on iOS with Xcode build, but I encounter the following issue when I run the yarn android command:
Error Messages:
Task :react-native-fast-opencv:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
C/C++: Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target
C/C++: "ReactAndroid::folly_runtime" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
C/C++: find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
C/C++: is missing?
C/C++: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
C/C++: Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target "ReactAndroid::glog" but
C/C++: the target was not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
C/C++: IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
C/C++: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
C/C++: Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target
C/C++: "ReactAndroid::reactnativejni" but the target was not found. Perhaps a
C/C++: find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
C/C++: is missing?
C/C++: CMake Generate step failed. Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.

Detailed Error Log:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fast-opencv:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using /Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/CMakeLists.txt: -- The C compiler identification is Clang 17.0.2
  -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 17.0.2
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  
  C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
      /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/cmake \
        -H/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
        -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=24 \
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 \
        -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DANDROID_NDK=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
        "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all" \
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/25j621p1/obj/arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/25j621p1/obj/arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
        -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/.cxx/Debug/25j621p1/prefab/arm64-v8a/prefab \
        -B/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/.cxx/Debug/25j621p1/arm64-v8a \
        -GNinja \
        -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared \
        -DNODE_MODULES_DIR=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules
    from /Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
    Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target
    "ReactAndroid::folly_runtime" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a
    find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
    is missing?
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
    Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target "ReactAndroid::glog" but
    the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
    IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
    Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target
    "ReactAndroid::reactnativejni" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a
    find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
    is missing?
  
  
  CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly. : com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: -- The C compiler identification is Clang 17.0.2
  -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 17.0.2
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  
  C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
      /Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/cmake \
        -H/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android \
        -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON \
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=24 \
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-24 \
        -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a \
        -DANDROID_NDK=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 \
        -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125 \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/vrtechsol/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.22.1/bin/ninja \
        "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-O2 -frtti -fexceptions -Wall -fstack-protector-all" \
        -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/25j621p1/obj/arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/25j621p1/obj/arm64-v8a \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
        -DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/.cxx/Debug/25j621p1/prefab/arm64-v8a/prefab \
        -B/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android/.cxx/Debug/25j621p1/arm64-v8a \
        -GNinja \
        -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared \
        -DNODE_MODULES_DIR=/Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules
    from /Users/vrtechsol/Documents/Projects/Derm_Pro/node_modules/react-native-fast-opencv/android
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
    Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target
    "ReactAndroid::folly_runtime" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a
    find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
    is missing?
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
    Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target "ReactAndroid::glog" but
    the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
    IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
  
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (add_library):
    Target "react-native-fast-opencv" links to target
    "ReactAndroid::reactnativejni" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a
    find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target
    is missing?

Steps to Reproduce:

Follow the setup instructions for react-native-fast-opencv.
Attempt to build the project using npx react-native run-android or yarn android

Additional Information
Library Version: "react-native-fast-opencv": "^0.3.1",
React Native Version: "react-native": "0.76.1",
Node Version: v18.18.0
Yarn Version: 3.6.4
Xcode Version: Version 16.0
macOS Version: 15.0.0

check this CMakeDebugFAILED

Its related to react-native-reanimated my reanimated configuration is fine, Everything was working smoothly my build failed after installing react-native-fast-opencv

I also have the same issue. Whenever I install a dependency and run the project, it shows me an error like this. Then, after removing white space from my project path, the problem was solved.

I your case Projects/Derm_Pro/. Try Projects/DermPro.
Check this CMakeDebugFAILED

I understand what you are trying to say but my project configuration was fine. I don't have whitespaces in my path its working fine on iOS, issue is related to react-native-fast-opencv configration.

I was able to resolve the issue with the
Task :react-native-fast-opencv:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
error during the android build process in terminal.
The problem was related to the version (^0.3.1) of react-native-fast-opencv with react native(0.76.1) during the debug release when i run the command yarn android .
After contacting the library maintainer, they pointed out that the issue was fixed in version v0.3.2.
I updated to this newer version, and the error was resolved successfully.
Solution:
Update react-native-fast-opencv to version v0.3.2 or above and run the command
yarn android
or
npx react-native run-android
Hope this helps others encountering the same issue!
